# Perl: Syncing two tables from different servers

Tags: mysql, perl

I already created a script that can perform sql commands. The problem is that I can't seem to make it work when it deals with two different servers. For example.

Inserting data from server 1's table A to server 2's table A.

I specified the server right before the database

```
insert into `server2`.`database`.`table` select * from `server1`.`database`.`table` where [conditions];
```

Applied the samples here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_database_access.htm

The problem is that I can't seem to make it work when trying commands for serverA to serverB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to break down this problem into two parts:

1. Create two DBI objects for Server1 & Server2, and connect.
2. Read data from server1.tableA into a resultset.
3. Iterate over the ResultSet and insert data into server2.tableA.

If your problem statement is just to sync two or more DBs, consider using following tool: pt-table-sync: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have already made it work thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. 
You'll need 2 DB connections, one to each server. 
Use one connection to read the data from the source DB and the other to insert it into the target DB.

The `inser`/`select` are DB commands, executed by MySQL. If you'd be able to issue such a command, you could execute it from the MySQL console and wouldn't need Perl (or other language) for this

Comment: I have created a function that could do a sql command.

$dev->_executeQuery("SET autocommit=0;");
$dev->_executeQuery("lock tables cluster write, `sample@server`.`id`.`cluster` read;");
$dev->_executeQuery("insert into `id`.`cluster` select * where `sample@server`.`id`.`cluster`.`db_id` = ?",[$db_id]);
$dev->_executeQuery("commit;");
$dev->_executeQuery("unlock tables;");

Although, it still does not work well.

Comment: The sql command you posted in your question, is not a valid sql command, so no function would be able to execute it, being it written in a bashed language or not.

Comment: Instead of doing it like this, Why don't you first fetch data from One Server.DB and after that insert it into another Server.DB.

Comment: @BashingPerl: Please show code and data by editing your question to include it. It's very difficult to read in a comment